# Watson Assistant over voice with Twilio SIP Caller ID

Tags: twilio, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I've seen the question about getting the caller id from Twilio over SIP asked, but never answered. Is it possible to get the caller id of the user in Watson Assistant? Maybe I'm missing something obvious? None of the state variables set by voice gateway seem to have the number of the caller or indicate anything I can tie back to Twilio to look the number up via their API either.

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears to be recorded in the vgwSIPFromURI state variable.  Looks like I did not examine that particular variable.